# D3 scatter plot points not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm new to d3, and I'm attempting a basic scatter plot using an example I found. Instead of using the read csv function in the example, I'm trying to add my own data.

Using the following code, it displays the axes, but only shows a single point at [0,10]. See picture below. What might I be missing?

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg2 = d3.select("#my_dataviz2")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //Read the data
    
    var data = [
        {"name": "point1", "x":1, "y":2},
        {"name": "point2", "x":3, "y":4},
        {"name": "point3", "x":5, "y":6},
        {"name": "point4", "x":7, "y":8}
    ];

    // Add X axis
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10])
        .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg2.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10])
        .range([ height, 0]);
    
    svg2.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Add dots
    svg2.append("g")
        .selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .style("fill", "#000");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>

<div id="my_dataviz2"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always helps to inspect your page when debugging D3 visualizations. When you do so here, you'll notice that all the points are added, they are just on top of each other at [0, 0] (in pixels).

This means we have have a positioning problem. Looking at your code you don't set where the circles should be on the page. Let's set cx and cy attributes by  scaling the data as follows:

```
    .attr("cx",d=>x(d.x))
    .attr("cy",d=>y(d.y))
```

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg2 = d3.select("#my_dataviz2")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //Read the data
    
    var data = [
        {"name": "point1", "x":1, "y":2},
        {"name": "point2", "x":3, "y":4},
        {"name": "point3", "x":5, "y":6},
        {"name": "point4", "x":7, "y":8}
    ];

    // Add X axis
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10])
        .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg2.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10])
        .range([ height, 0]);
    
    svg2.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Add dots
    svg2.append("g")
        .selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .style("fill", "#000")
        .attr("cx",d=>x(d.x))
        .attr("cy",d=>y(d.y))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>

<div id="my_dataviz2"></div>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I somehow removed that part from the example.